# Can't connect to a docker running flask app when network=host

Tags: docker, flask

I have an flask app running on docker. the host = 0.0.0.0 and the port is 5001. If I run the docker without network=host I'm able to connect to 0.0.0.0 on port 5001, but with network=host I can't. I need the network=host because I need to connect to a db outside of the docker network cluster (which I'm able to connect to).
How can I do that? I tried running the docker with proxy but that didn't help.

Steps to reproduce:

Install python and flask (I'm using 3.8.6 and 1.1.2). In your main, create a flask app and expose one REST endpoint (the Url doesn't really matter).
This is my flask_main file:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/')
def route():
    return "got to route"
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = 0.0.0.0, port=5001)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.6
WORKDIR /
ADD . /.
RUN pip --proxy ***my_proxy*** install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5001
CMD ["python", "flask_main.py"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
psycopg2==2.8.6
Werkzeug==1.0.1
click==7.1.2
```

I tried running the Dockerfile with and without proxy, tried to remove the host=0.0.0.0 but nothing helps.

Comment: In most cases you should be able to just connect to the remote host.  Specifying host networking generally disables most of Docker's network functionality, including the standard inter-container communication setup.  Can you provide a [mcve] describing the setup that doesn't work?

Comment: @DavidMaze added in the question, please have a look.

Comment: Hi David, maybe you have an insight about it? Really stuck here..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by removing the network=host and specifying the dns server of my company.